# Algorithm to reverse engineer permutation

Tags: algorithms

I have a sequence of permutations formed using these strings: `"A"`, `"BC"` and `"D"`. The permutations are:

```
BCAD
ABCD
BCDA
DABC
ADBC
DBCA
```

Now I need to reverse engineer this; i.e. I have a text file containing the sequences, I should be able to tell the strings that are used to construct the permutations. What algorithm I can use?

Comment: Do you always get all n! permutations to work with, or just some?

Comment: All permutations should work with.

Comment: Would the source strings "AB", "CD" produce the same set of permutations as "A", "BC", "D"? If no, how will they differ?

Comment: (and if yes, they produce the same permutations, then you have your answer)

Comment: Nope here "A", "BD" "D" are different sets so they will only produce 3! = 6 permutations. "BC" is a single element.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) and can be solved using a [Generalized suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_suffix_tree).

Use Ukkonen's algorithm to [Build a tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm) (not a binary tree), adding nodes as you parse the file. Ukkonen's algorithm works in O(n) (linear) time, for constant-size alphabets, and O(n log n) in general.

The leaf nodes of the tree can then be traversed to obtain the original sequences.